# Loop method until it returns falsey

Tags: ruby

I was trying to make my bubble sort shorter and I came up with this

```
class Array
  def bubble_sort!(&block)
    block = Proc.new { |a, b| a <=> b } unless block_given?
    sorted = each_index.each_cons(2).none? do |i, next_i|
      if block.call(self[i], self[next_i]) == 1
        self[i], self[next_i] = self[next_i], self[i]
      end
    end until sorted
    self
  end

  def bubble_sort(&prc)
    self.dup.bubble_sort!(&prc)
  end
end
```

I don't particularly like the thing with `sorted = --sort code-- until sorted`.

I just want to run the `each_index.each_cons(s).none?` code until it returns true. It's a weird situation that I use `until`, but the condition is a code I want to run. Any way, my try seems awkward, and ruby usually has a nice concise way of putting things. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @ForeverZer0 Almost every bubble sort implementation in existence is a learning exercise, speed and efficiency are rarely the prime objective in such cases. In-place modification is usually the exception in Ruby (hence, `#map`, `#sort`, `#upcase`, `#gsub`, ... appearing more often than `#map!`, `#sort!`, `#upcase!`, `#gsub!`, ... in idiomatic Ruby).

Comment: Yeah, it's just a learning exercise. I'm hoping there's a more idiomatic way to keep running the method until it returns nil or false, but I haven't found one. (Of course, I could write my own method to do it, but I'm looking for a method in the standard library.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into it further I'm fairly sure the best solution is

```
loop do
  break if condition
end
```

Either that or the way I have it in the question, but I think the `loop do` version is clearer.

Edit:

Ha, a couple weeks later after I settled for the `loop do` solution, I stumbled into a better one. You can just use a `while` or `until` loop with an empty block like this:

```
while condition; end

until condition; end
```

So the bubble sort example in the question can be written like this

```
class Array
  def bubble_sort!(&block)
    block = Proc.new { |a, b| a <=> b } unless block_given?
    until (each_index.each_cons(2).none? do |i, next_i|
      if block.call(self[i], self[next_i]) == 1
        self[i], self[next_i] = self[next_i], self[i]
      end
    end); end
    self
  end

  def bubble_sort(&prc)
    self.dup.bubble_sort!(&prc)
  end
end
```

Comment: Read a book on ruby. You'll find the solution there

Answer (score 2):

This is just my opinion

**have you ever read the ruby source code of `each` and `map` to understand what they do**?

No, because they have a clear task expressed from the method name and if you test them, they will take an object, some parameters and then return a value to you.

For example if I want to test the `String` method `split()`

```
s = "a new string"
s.split("new") 
=> ["a ", " string"]
```

Do you know if `.split()` takes a `block`? 
It is one of the core ruby methods, but to call it I don't pass a block 90% of the times, I can understand what it does from the name `.split()` and from the return value

Focus on the objects you are using, the task the methods should accomplish and their return values.

I read your code and I can not refactor it, I hardly can understand what the code does.

I decided to write down some points, with possibility to follow up:

1) do not use the `proc` for now, first get the Object Oriented code clean.

2) split `bubble_sort!` into several methods, each one with a clear task

`def ordered_inverted!` (bubble_sort!), `def invert_values`, maybe perform a `invert_values until sorted`, check if existing methods already perform this sorting functionality

3) write specs for those methods, tdd will push you to keep methods simple and easy to test

4) If those methods do not belong to the Array class, include them in the appropriate class, sometimes overly complicated methods are just performing simple `String` operations.

5) Reading books about refactoring may actually help more then trying to force the usage of `proc` and functional programming when not necessary.

Comment: This is good advice, but it doesn't actually answer the question.